# Can solar mirrors be used for amateur telescopes?

Tags: optics, astronomy, telescopes

Recently I have been fascinated by astronomy and telescopes. I have a small refactor telescope, but it cannot see very far, so I was interested in buying a larger telescope. Unfortunately, I cannot afford to purchase a good quality telescope, so I was trying to think of how I can make one by myself for a cheaper price.

So, my question is, is it possible to use [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/13-SOLAR-ACRYLIC-PARABOLIC-MIRROR-PROFESSIONALLY-MADE-REAL-SOLAR-MIRROR/173159202780?_trkparms=aid%3D333200%26algo%3DCOMP.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20190129125700%26meid%3Da3a6015c2160409db2902a285ecde890%26pid%3D100752%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D8%26sd%3D183296078136%26itm%3D173159202780&_trksid=p2047675.c100752.m1982) kind of parabolic solar reflector as a primary mirror for a decent amateur telescope? I am not looking for perfect, crystal clear images. Rather, I just want to see the Moon and the solar system close up for myself! :)

PS: I saw this [thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76329/could-a-mirror-array-used-for-thermal-solar-power-plant-double-as-a-telescope-at) with a similar question, but the answer was focused on high-quality professional telescopes. I'm not looking to do any science with this telescope. Just observing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. Just by looking at the reflection pattern in the photo, you can see that the consistency of focus across the surface of the mirror is lousy- certainly good enough for lighting ants on fire, but nowhere near good enough to produce good images.

If you live in or near a big city, you probably have an amateur astronomy club nearby. Many members of these clubs make their own telescopes from kits by grinding their own mirrors (it is possible!) at modest cost.